# failed to resolve channel name

Tags: spring, spring-ws, spring-integration

I am stuck with very unusal problem. I am using header-value-router in my spring integration flow (ver 2.1.0)in a spring webservice component
Like:

```
<int:header-value-router id="routerId" input-channel="routeChannel"
    header-name="msgtype" resolution-required="true">
<int:mapping value="north" channel="channelA"/>
<int:mapping value="south" channel="channelB"/>
 </int:header-value-router>
```

This works perfectly when I invoke the flow via JUnit, but when this webserivce is component is deployed in tcserver and webservice invokes the SI flow, it fails at header-value-router with following error

```
[16.01.2013 23:14:25] WARN:GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway.doSendAndReceive() - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive

**org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'north'**
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:168)
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addChannelFromString(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:197)
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addToCollection(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:218)
```

I debugged spring source and found that when header-value-router is invoked the mappings are loaded but are not compared properly in the source code 
AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java

```
   if (this.channelMappings.containsKey(channelKey)) {
                    channelName = this.channelMappings.get(channelKey);
    }
```

This failure at 'containsKey' leads to code in assuming the header value has channelName.

Not sure what is the problem. May if some jar missing at runtime ? I even tried xpath-router and router, but the result is the same

Comment: Strange - when you run the debugger, can you see the contents of channelMappings? Does it contain 'north' and 'south' as keys? If it was something other than String, I would have said it's a classloader issue, but that shouldn't be a problem with String.

Comment: Yes Gary, the contents of channelMappings did have string keys 'north' and 'south'

Comment: Then I have no immediate clue as to what is going on. If was to debug this, my next step with the debugger would be to step into 'containsKey()' and figure out why it returns false.